# Cpu overuse replicating a Gluster Volume

Tags: glusterfs

I've this scenario:

srv01
srv02
srv03

there is a gluster volume "vol1" running on srv03, and all the servers can use for i/o. vol1 contains a lot of mixed side images, ranging from few kbs to 3-4Mb, The total amount is about 1.5TB.

Gluster version is 3.6.2

It's not a silver bullet, need some tuning, but works pretty well.

Now I've to replicate srv03's brick to the other servers.

The problem is that srv03's cpu skyrockets to 100% and cannot serve normal
requests. Net traffic is low.

Options are:

cluster.data-self-heal-algorithm: full

cluster.self-heal-daemon: off

performance.cache-size: 1gb

I've to keep the service running while the replication is running, Your suggestions are welcome

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you prefer 'full' algorithm more than the 'reset' one?

Comment: key = "cluster.data-self-heal-algorithm"
 value = "diff"|"full"

there is no diff algorithm in documentation

Comment: Maybe outdated, but http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/Gluster_3.2:_Setting_Volume_Options#cluster.data-self-heal-algorithm says "Selects between "full", "diff", and reset."

Answer (score 0):

I am somehow working on a similar situation. If your bottleneck is the CPU I think that decreasing `cluster.background-self-heal-count` should help (default is 16).
In other words "when your client tries to open 17 files, it'll hang on the 17th waiting for a self-heal" (https://botbot.me/freenode/gluster/msg/45681458/).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to test this parameter. If you are right the default value is simple crazy and the documention needs an integration.

Comment: FYI, unfortunately I didn't see any difference while configuring that parameter; maybe a restart was required. I then started to trigger self-heal selectively with a `find . -print0 | xargs --null stat`.